# Run .exe with some params

Tags: php, windows, exec

I have to generate .txt file then use it with .exe file on my server.

Firstly, I make for example somefile.txt. Then I use .bat command to open .exe file with params:
`"qb.exe -c somefile.txt > somefile.qb"`

I need to do it on server automatically after pushing the "Generate" button.
Any ideas how to make it on php?

I know about *shell_exec()* (found somewhere) and *exec()*, but how can I use params (*-c file.txt>file.qb*)?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hakre alludes to in the comment: You can pass parameters as part of the command.

For example:

```
exec('qb.exe -c file.txt > file.qb');
```

You may find [Program Execution in PHP: exec, system, passthru, and shell_exec, oh my!](http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@) useful for determining which of PHP’s many program execution functions best fits your needs.